# Unable to load native library libmain.so when cross compiling to Android when using OpenSSL

Tags: android, android-ndk, openssl, rust, rust-cargo

I have some troubles using OpenSSL with [cargo-apk](https://crates.io/crates/cargo-apk).

I've provided **libssl.so**, **libcrypto.so**, and **openssl** includes to android-ndk and use `PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_CROSS=1 cargo-apk` with a custom build script:

```
fn main () {
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=crypto");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=ssl");
}
```

Compilation succeeded, but when I run my application, I get the following logs using `adb logcat` and the application crashes.

```
I/Timeline( 1715): Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:rust.fantafs time:48384944
V/ApplicationPolicy( 1184): isApplicationStateBlocked userId 0 pkgname rust.fantafs
W/ActivityManager( 1184): NORMAL SET : srcAppInfo.processName = com.sec.android.app.launcher, destAppInfo.processName = rust.fantafs
V/ApplicationPolicy( 1184): isApplicationStateBlocked userId 0 pkgname rust.fantafs
I/ActivityManager( 1184): Start proc rust.fantafs for activity rust.fantafs/.MainActivity: pid=1008 uid=10228 gids={50228, 9997, 3003, 1028, 1015} abi=armeabi
E/AndroidRuntime( 1008): Process: rust.fantafs, PID: 1008
E/AndroidRuntime( 1008): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{rust.fantafs/rust.fantafs.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to load native library: /data/app/rust.fantafs-1/lib/arm/libmain.so
E/AndroidRuntime( 1008): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to load native library: /data/app/rust.fantafs-1/lib/arm/libmain.so
V/ApplicationPolicy( 1184): isApplicationStateBlocked userId 0 pkgname rust.fantafs
W/ActivityManager( 1184):   Force finishing activity rust.fantafs/.MainActivity
V/ApplicationPolicy( 1184): isApplicationStateBlocked userId 0 pkgname rust.fantafs
W/ActivityManager( 1184): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{1a641bc7 u0 rust.fantafs/.MainActivity t150 f}
I/ActivityManager( 1184): Process rust.fantafs (pid 1008)(adj 11) has died(77,169)
```

Here's my **main.rs**:

```
extern crate openssl;

use openssl::rand::rand_bytes;

fn main() {
    let mut a: [u8; 5] = [0,1,2,8,6];
    match rand_bytes(&mut a) {
        Ok(_) => println!("Success"),
        Err(_) => println!("ERR"),
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tested the same code without using OpenSSL?

Comment: I need openssl because i'm using hyper-native-tls, so i can't just remove it. PS: thank you for edited my post

Comment: I was trying to suggest that you attempt to narrow down the source of the problem. If you remove OpenSSL and the problem still occurs, you now have a smaller location to look for the root cause. If it doesn't occur, you also have a smaller location to look.

Comment: How can I do smaller than that main.rs? This principal is not really my code, it is an example. I tell you that I do not want to remove openssl